# Facebook Graph API, get email from users who have already given email permission, but they are not logged in

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I own an application which has already granted the send-email extended permission. Unfortunately I didn't record the email address's upon their login process. Is there any way to get email of users now, even if they are not logged in?

Keep in mind that they have already granted the email extended permission, but unfortunately I didn't store their emails.

Answer (score 0):

If you recorded their Facebook user ID, you could try to call graph.facebook.com/userID?access_token=...  with your application access token or appID|appSecret.

Comment: Hi again. are you sure about it? I have tried it but unfortunately doesn't return the email within the other profile information even if the user has granted the email permission. any other tip? Its a shame i cannot get that info.

Comment: Then you probably need the users access token, and unless you received offline_access to begin with; the user tokens are probably expired.

Comment: no i dont have offline access :( i have the latest access_tokens of users but they have expired and i cannot get anything out of it :(

Thats not right! I have the email permission and normally i could have the ability to send an email whenever i like and Facebook API doesnt mention that i should record the emails as well.

Comment: The documentation does say user access tokens expires in 1-2 hours.